# Replace Parent component with Child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to hide the content or JSX of Parent component and show JSX of child component when some button is clicked.

There are two components `ABC` and `XYZ`.

Desired behavior: when button is clicked `XYZ` component should be rendered within the same div with className sidebar, but JSX of component `ABC` should be hidden now.

Currently, when I click button, `XYZ` renders while `ABC` is still there.

Any ideas, how can I achieve this?

```
class ABC extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div className="sidebar">
     <h1>This is component ABC</h1>
    </div>
  }
}

class XYZ extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div className="sidebar">
      <h1>Replaced by XYZ</h1>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: use conditional rendering buttonClick === true ? XYZ : ABC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render `<XYZ />` or `<ABC />` depends on `isClicked` flag.

Below codes show how to render each child component in certain condition.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { isClicked: false };
  render() {
    <div className="sidebar">
      { this.tate.isClicked ? <XYZ /> : <ABC /> }
    </div>
  }
}
```

Then you need to update `isClicked` flag in parent component.

Comment: @Antonia Actually, ABC is a parent component to XYZ. It would be already there with some button. When button is clicked, All I want is to replace <h1> of ABC with <h1> of XYZ remaining in same div.

Comment: @Meana Without using conditional rendering of children, you need to think about the DOM operation. But it is not recommended in react js.
Even though if you have button to change flag in `<XYZ />` you can do that by using conditional rendering.